# Assign Text in Code to UILabel! Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uilabel

Using a tutorial from iOS 8/Swift 1 to create a sample app in an attempt to assign text to a label, using Xcode 7.3/Swift 2.2.  Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var ageCat: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var resultAge: UILabel!

    @IBAction func findAgeButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        var enteredAge = Int(ageCat.text!)

        var catYears = enteredAge! * 7

        resultAge = "Your cat is \(catYears) in cat years"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace your IBAction func findAgeButton with the following:

```
@IBAction func findAgeButton(sender: AnyObject) {

// Here the variable is unwrapped. This means the code after it is not executed unless the program is sure that it contains a value.
if let text =  ageCat.text {
    // You can use the unwrapped variable now and won't have to place an exclamation mark behind it to force unwrap it. 
    let enteredAge = Int(text)
     if let age  = enteredAge {
      let catYears = age * 7
      resultAge.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) in cat years"
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should make sure that the text is numeric and don`t the force unwrapping.

Comment: After using code above, I get this error "Initialization of immutable value 'catYears' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it".  Entering "3" in text field results in catYears = 140316326775648.  After "let catYears" line get Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1 3.1, and text on next line after "resultAge.text =" is red.  Label does not change in simulator.  Your code looks good to me but what do I know.  Wondering if running Xcode as VM could be a factor.

Comment: Ok a bunch of stuff is going wrong! Let's start with the first issue. Stuff complaining about '_'. Are you sure you've got this line in there?: resultAge.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) in cat years"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the helpful input.  This worked for me:

```
@IBAction func findAgeButton(sender: AnyObject) {

     var catYears = Int(ageCat.text!)!

     catYears = catYears * 7

     resultAge.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) in cat years"

  }
```

I also added an if/else to address nil entries:

```
if Int(ageCat.text!) != nil {

    // --insert last 3 lines of code from above here--

  } else {

    resultAge.text = "Please enter a number"

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign value to resultAge.text instead of resultAge:

```
resultAge.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) in cat years"
```

Comment: in swift this is called string interpolation.

Comment: Doesn't matter how you name it, it is still not what OP asked for

Comment: as you saw the question please look the (resultAge) is UIlabel variable  and he is directly asign a value to label . UILabel have a property "Text" to asign text to it. so please look in it.